# Right syntax to use near order by id desc limit 1

Tags: php, mysql

If the code is executed, it shows the error:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY ID DESC limit 1'

Like in the following example:

```
$prevquery = "SELECT  * FROM $tbl_name WHERE  ID < $ID ORDER BY ID DESC limit 1";
$prevresult= mysql_query($prevquery) or die(mysql_error());

while($prevrow = mysql_fetch_row($prevresult))
{

  displaying the previous ID:-
  $prevID = $prevrow['ID'];
}
```

What should one do to prevent this?

Comment: What are `$tbl_name` and `$ID` evaluated into?

Comment: Please show us what `$prevquery` contains.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$prevquery = "SELECT  * FROM $tbl_name WHERE  ID < '$ID' ORDER BY ID DESC limit 1";
```

If this does not work then echo the query and run in mysql phpmyadmin panel

```
echo $prevquery = "SELECT  * FROM $tbl_name WHERE  ID < '$ID' ORDER BY ID DESC limit 1";
```

Comment: when i echo and c...it shows that "query is empty" though the tablename and everything is right

Answer (score 0):

This should work

$prevquery = "SELECT  * FROM $tbl_name WHERE  ID < '$ID' ORDER BY ID DESC limit 1";

$prevresult= mysql_query($prevquery) or die(mysql_error());

while($prevrow = mysql_fetch_row($prevresult))
{

displaying the previous ID:-
  $prevID = $prevrow['ID'];
}

Answer (score 0):

An additional note, whenever I see a generic error of the form...

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY ID DESC limit 1'

The hint to look "near" almost always points to a problem in the sql statement just prior to where the single-quoted string shown in the error message begins.

So in this case the error quotes your sql string beginning at 'ORDER BY' which is immediately preceded by $ID. I would bet $ID is either not defined (and ends up being blank in your sql string), or $ID is not the correct data type.

Either way, as others have suggested you need to echo or log your sql string to see what is actually being queried.

Answer (score 0):

You cant user 'where' with LIMIT. Instead use ORDER by id desc LIMIT 1